# Android Studio "there is nothing to install or update" while Loading Bar is not stopping

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I've tried to install Android Studio on a Windows 7 PC. I'm afraid, it's stuck behind a very strict configured Proxy, so, Android Studio and the Android SDK Manager are not able to access the Internet. I've downloaded and installed the m2repositorys for google and android and the 4.2.2 Platform manually and now, Android Studio doesn't complain about a misconfigured SDK anymore. But now, while creating a new Studio Project, Android Studio just shows a loading bar with the message "there is nothing to install or to update" which doesn't disappear ever.
Is something missing in my tinkered configuration? I suspect a broken 4.2.2 Platform, but I do not know, where to get another one, because I've downloaded it from the official google website.